# How to make nested loops in R more efficient

Tags: r, performance, loops, dataframe

so basically I have two separate groups within a data frame: I have a  names of locations and the associated latitude and longitude ranges, and then I have a list of exact lat and long values. What I want to do is for each EXACT lat/long pair, iterate through the lat/long RANGE to see if the pair falls within the range. If it does, I want to write the name of the location next to the lat/long pair.

So, my code DOES work. However, it takes about 40 minutes to run though. I don't know if this is normal or if I'm doing this in a terribly structured/inefficient way. Any thoughts and input would be creatively appreciated!

```
for (x in 1:35274) {
  lat = test[x,9]
  long = test[x,10]
  for (y in 1:1198) {
    if ((((test[y,3] <= lat) & (lat <= test[y,2])) &
         ((test[y,4] <= long) & (test[y,5] >= long))) == TRUE)
      test[x,12] <- test[y,1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Read http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf You should be able to get rid of most loops.

Comment: Can you edit with the results of `dput` on a representative sample data set? And yes, these loops are unnecessary. Vectorize; it's the R way.

Comment: looks like you dont even need to loop over y, just do all the y rows at once

Comment: I suspect that findINterval would be very useful but for this sort of question I don't build example datasts ... that is _your_ responsibility!

Comment: Please provide a _minimal, self contained_ example: see [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all you are doing here is selecting the first 35274 entries of `test[,9]` and `test[,10]`, but you are doing it one value at a time. It's better to just do this all in one go:

```
n <- 1:35274
lat <- test[n,9]
long <- test[n,10]
```

Then, within your 35274 loops you do another 1198 loops, which is a lot of operations to run (42,258,252 loops!). This is probably where you're having some problems. This also seems like it is not achieving what you want. Basically, for any given `x`, if multiple `y` satisfy the conditions, only the last `y` will be written down and any `y` before that will be overwritten. In other words, if there are multiple locations that fall within the range of your lat/long, then only one will be written down.

Assuming that you only expect one location per `x`, you can reduce this to 1198 loops by simply doing this:

```
m <- 1198
vec <- rep(NA,m)
for (y in 1:m){
  ind <- (test[y,3] <= lat) & (test[y,2] >= lat) & (test[y,4] <= long) & (test[,5] >= long)
  vec[y] <- test[which(ind),1]
}
```

If multiple locations are possible, simply use `lis <- list()` to initialize and then store with `lis[y] <- test[which(ind),1]`.

There are probably better ways to do this as well, but this should already save you a lot of time.